# Do I need to do anything special to my application built with Sails version 0.9.9 when upgrading to version 0.10.x?

Tags: npm, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am currently working on an application using Sails version 0.9.9 but I want to upgrade to utilize the new support for data model associations.  I found [this article](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/Migration-Guide) about migrating applications from 0.8.x to 0.9.x but is there anything I should do to safely upgrade my application from 0.9.x to 0.10.x?

Comment: Check out the following docs regarding upgrading in sails (version 0.9x to 0.10x) http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/Upgrading/Upgrading.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this doc doesn't list specific instructions on how to safely upgrade and migrate your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `npm update sails -g` and my application starts up and runs the same as it used to.  I'm guessing it was a simple enough app that it isn't affected by the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  A lot has changed in the latest version.  Check out this [link](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Upgrading). Also, make sure you check out [the website](http://beta.sailsjs.org) for the newest documentation on v0.10

Comment: I found that upgrade doc on the Sails site but it doesn't seem to say anything about what actually needs to be done to upgrade, but rather how to do new things in your 0.10.x application.  And when I checked this morning the doc was empty..

Comment: That link is just a template page with no content, and the docs contain no link that I can find to how to upgrade from v0.9 to v0.10